# Is cyclic pattern observable in this plot?

Tags: time-series, trend

I have a data that measures the annual production of bituminous coal between 1920 and 1968 and created a plot. Would it be alright to conclude this plot is cyclic as fluctuations exist?

[image: img]

Comment: It depends on what you mean by cyclic: it went down then up then down then up, but this was caused by external factors (e.g. the Great Depression and WWII) not because a high level of coal production leads to a long term decline in coal production to below the long-term average and similarly in the opposite direction

Comment: I was referring to the definition of cyclic pattern: data exhibiting rises and falls that are not of fixed period

Comment: That may be one definition of cyclic pattern, but it is not universal. I don't think it makes much sense to think of cycles unless the period is approximately fixed. Naturally, that just switches attention to _approximately_. This is discipline-dependent: economists and others very likely have a looser idea of cycles (business cycles, anyone?) than say physical scientists. But with your definition @Henry has an answer: sure, it goes up and and down. The weaker the definition, the emptier it is for description, let alone analysis.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, it's almost impossible to detect cycles unless you have data that span at least two full periods--and usually at least three periods are needed.  After all, with two periods all you have is the apparent coincidence of some up-down pattern across the first and second half of the data--and that often could just be a coincidence.  The third period serves as partial confirmation of any such pattern.  Because the down-up-down-up trend in the example spans at most two periods, most people would hesitate to claim they have detected cyclicality.

Comment: I would say "No." What is your explanation for the seasonality? Most seasonality (periodic behavior) is based on annual periods, but your seasonal plot has a frequency of every five years. Coal production, it seems to me, would be much more dependent on events such as the Great Depression, rather than seasonal effects.

Comment: I see, then does the plot itself look alright? To be honest, I've never seen a fit that doesn't really follow the original trend.

Comment: The dotted line, to me, explains nothing, I'm afraid. It does not explain the higher numbers in the 1920's, the lower numbers in the 1930s, the higher numbers in the 1940s, and the medium numbers in the 1950s and 1960s. World events such as the "Roaring 20's", the Great Depression, WWII, and FDR's abysmal policies such as the New Deal, can probably explain a lot of the variation you see there.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, Soviets had 5 year plans, and they excavated a lot of coal. MAybe they were trying to hit the numbers before the end of 5 year period :)

Answer (score 1):

- As discussed in the comments, there’s no single definition of cyclic patterns. The question is impossible to answer until we agree on the definition.
- But talking this aside, you have a very small sample. You observed two rises-and-falls, so what? If a red car passed your house at 8 AM two days in a row would you conclude it’s a cyclical pattern? Surely not.

So considering both points, without a precise definition of cyclicity and with only two “cycles” in the data, this would be a very weak argument.

Answer (score 0):

Why eyeball it? You can apply a statistical test. Using the seasonal regression you already obtained, use a nested likelihood ratio test against the intercept-only regression. This is a three degree of freedom test. If the result is significant, you can conclude at least one seasonal effect differs from the global average trendline.